# Setting value of Date Picker on single onChange

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datetime, onchange

I am trying to set the date for two of my different input types. I tried calling different functions for both input event handler, and it worked. But I want to use more concise way to manage input date. The different approach I tried calling single onChange(), doesn't seem to change my input box value.

Here is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

export default class DatePage extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      startDate: '',
      endDate: '',
      clicked: false
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {

    this.setDate();



    this.setState({
        clicked: true
      });
  }

  setDate = (e) => {

    if (this.state.clicked !== true) 
    {
      var date = new Date();

      var newdate =
        date.getFullYear() + "-" + ("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)) + "-" + date.getDate();

      this.setState({
        startDate: newdate,
        endDate: newdate,
        clicked: false
      });
    } 

    else 
    {

        this.setState({
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value
        });
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>

        <label>From</label>
        <input
          type="date"
          name="startdate"
          value={this.state.startDate}
          onChange={this.setDate}

        />

        <label>To</label>
        <input
          type="date"
          name="enddate"
          value={this.state.endDate}
          onChange={this.setDate}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

By default,  I am setting the current date and onChange the date selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the case is wrong. I cleaned up the code.

startdate to startDate
enddate to endDate. It seems to work well if you change this part.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";


export default class Datepage extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    var date = new Date();
    var newdate =
      date.getFullYear() + "-" + ("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)) + "-" + date.getDate();

    this.state = {
      startdate: newdate,
      enddate: newdate,
      clicked: false
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
  }

  setDate = (e) => {    
      this.setState({
          [e.target.name]: e.target.value
      });    
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>

        <label>From</label>
        <input
          type="date"
          name="startdate"
          value={this.state.startdate}
          onChange={this.setDate.bind(this)}

        />

        <label>To</label>
        <input
          type="date"
          name="enddate"
          value={this.state.enddate}
          onChange={this.setDate.bind(this)}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This Worked. Thanks Mate. Can you please explain me why we need to bind the onChange(setDate) function again when we are using fat-arrow?

Comment: This still won't be working because of `name="startdate"` and `name="enddate"`

Comment: You can not use "this" unless you bind it. you can check https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html or  https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/this-is-why-we-need-to-bind-event-handlers-in-class-components-in-react-f7ea1a6f93eb/

Comment: @DorianMazur this code worked, I guess you didn't get the code right.

Comment: Oh, you changed letters in construct method as well. Huh, but I was first :D

Comment: @Ray Just a confirmation. What I followed from the links you provided, If we're to use fat-arrow function, we don't need to .bind the function. It will only create new function everytime. But In case, if we have to send some extra parameter along with the event, then we can use this.bind over that function or again define it using arrow function.    I replaced `onChange={this.setDate.bind(this)}` with `onChange={this.setDate}` , and it also worked :)   Is it right?

Answer (score 3):

You need to correct names in the form.

from:
`name="startdate"`
to
`name="startDate"`

Also, here:
`name="enddate"`
to
`name="endDate"`

Comment: Still doesn't work. And also if I am using arrow-function notation, I don't require to bind the function

Comment: Add `console.log` to setDate function and check if it's showing something.

Comment: Console is not showing proper state. Here is the working code: `https://codesandbox.io/embed/tender-banach-evgl7`